# Fast lookup for 100gb of data

Tags: database-design

I have about 100GB of data saved in ~10MB .csv files.  How can I optimize lookup speed for several thousand queries to this data?  Specifically, I don't know what technologies to consider or how to estimate relative performance.

Each file is unique to a date, and contains data for multiple people, for example:

```
...
2005-07-03, "Daffy Duck", ...
2005-07-03, "Daffy Duck", ...
2005-07-03, "Mickey Mouse", ...
2005-07-03, "Mickey Mouse", ...
...
```

I want to pull all of the info corresponding with a given date/name, for several thousand date/name pairs.  The equivalent SQL query would be `SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE Date='2005-07-03' AND Name='Mickey Mouse'`.

Currently I haven't loaded the data into a database.  To execute my "queries", I locate the appropriate date file and filter the lines by the name I am looking for.  Would I get performance improvements storing the data in a relational database, noSQL database, or in any other way?  If so why and by how much?

Comment: "several thousand date/name pairs" how long does this currently take you?

Comment: Before any of the answers really make sense, the core issue is - how repeatable, maintainable, scalable does this need to be?  Is this a full blown piece of a business application or something that is accessed rarely?  While a db will definitely, definitely be *faster* for access, @caderoux's comment that you might fast enough given a db's increased complexity might be true.  And there's not going to be any answers of 'how much faster' it will be until you give us an idea of how fast it currently is for you.

Comment: err "comment that you might **be** fast enough , give a db's ..."

Comment: Basically, I am pulling all the rows for each date/name pair for somewhere between 10k and 100k pairs.  I wrote a ruby script to open relevant files, gather rows for the name, and do a small amount of analysis on the extracted data.  It took a few hours to extract 95k rows on my modestly powered machine. (My script may not have been optimized, but no glaring errors -- I read each file no more than once.)  I would like to pull rows in miliseconds rather than seconds, to make this an operation I can feasibly repeat.

Comment: Oh my goodness...you could pull 95k rows in a few seconds probably.

Comment: @orlandpm Definitely load it in a relational database, then...

Comment: Sounds like you may want one table with all your data and another table with your name,date combination and then just JOIN the two together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Would I get performance improvements storing the data in a relational database, noSQL database, or in any other way?*

yes (I'd recommend a 'normal' RDBMS)

> *If so why…*

that's one of the things indexes are for

> *…and by how much?*

lots

Comment: It certainly could, several books worth at least ;)

Comment: A little elaboration wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I have used relational databases for "organizing" data before, but never for performance, so I am not just asking _if_ it is a good idea, but also _why_ ... I think it would be helpful to understand what is going on under the hood when I use an index.  Any suggestions on resources?

Comment: @orlandpm performance is relative, but surely anything would be faster than doing this manually? Internally 'normal' indexes are a ['b-tree'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) which like a binary tree but optimised for block-based storage.

Comment: The effects of normalization on the size of the data will be enormous, too. Given the small sample we have, there is some repeated content. There's probably much more repeatedness to be removed by normalization.

Comment: @orlandpm - the short answer to 'why' is because basically databases and relational databases are made specifically for these kinds of things.  The data is organized and indexed *for these types of things*. Searching 100GB of data with a properly indexed table with a simple two column equality check will be lightning fast on any modern hardware/modern database.

Comment: @orlandpm _Any suggestions on resources?_ Take a look at http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a devil's advocate limb here and say that you might not get that much better performance with a relational database or any other database "system" for this particular operation relative to the work required to put all this data into a database.

As much as I would recommend loading the data into some kind of database (i.e. a full-blown codified data management system), your files are tiny.  From your question, it sounds like you can identify the file needed in constant time and then only have to read and filter (using a regex perhaps?) at most 10MB of data, so why would you need a relational database?

Just identify the file and pipe it through grep and you're done, right?  That's pretty efficient.

The relational database with appropriate indexing (on date, name), is only going to make the second step more efficient, and even then, the data set is fairly small - a few thousand rows in each 10MB file?

I know this sounds like a very rough way to solve the problem by keeping everything in the text files, but keep it simple.  You would have to manage the parsing, validation and loading of the data into the database, and then manage the additional storage of the data in database form etc.

You haven't given any information about how frequently you need to carry out this search, what you do with the data you obtain as a result or any other performance and operational requirements.

If you were needing to carry out this particular operation many times a second or want to have flexibility in addressing the data in more creative fashion or perform any kind of analysis across data which is currently in separate files or any number of things like that, then the relational database immediately presents itself as the best option for data management.

Comment: In terms of raw speed (which is what the question asks - about 'performance') - I have trouble believing that locating the file and 'grep'ing is faster than a b-tree search.

Comment: @rfusca but he will have to load and maintain the database - so I'm wondering what the underlying problem we're solving is

Comment: Oh I wonder too.  And truth be told, 'my dba'ness' probably vastly under estimates the difficultly of loading the db for developer, but I just can't seem to justify encouraging the madness that is a massive collection of files like that when there are effective tools designed specifically to solve the problem of locating specific pieces of data in large sets.

Comment: I'm willing to take any reasonable amount of overhead to create a database, and new data insertion will be infrequent.  I really want consistently low lookup speed.

Comment: @orlandpm Load it in a database, index on date, name (or normalize the names to a separate table, which is indexed on name).  Without seeing the whole data, it's again, not easy to speculate on the best model for your data or the best indexing strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already provided some good points, let me just talk a bit about physical database structure...

If you can, pick a DBMS that supports [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)<sup>1</sup> and make a clustered (aka. index-organized) table whose PK is `{Date, Name, No}`<sup>2</sup>. Your SELECT can then be satisfied with a simple index range scan and no heap access at all (the table heap doesn't even exist), so you don't have to worry about bad [clustering factor](http://oracle-online-help.blogspot.com/2006/11/clustering-factor_28.html). The practical performance should be excellent and scale well to even much more data than you currently have.

If your DBMS supports [leading-edge index compression](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/02/17/index-compression-part-i-low/), turn it on to eliminate the storage (and cache) cost of repeating values in the B-Tree structure of this composite primary/clustering index.

---

*<sup>1</sup> E.g. Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL/InnoDB...*

*<sup>2</sup> Where `No` distinguishes between multiple rows on the same `Date` with the same `Name`. Alternatively, just make the `Date` more granular (e.g. make it precise to a second), modify the query to: `SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE Name='Mickey Mouse' AND Date >= '2005-07-03' AND Date < '2005-07-04')`, and reverse the order of PK fields to `{Name, Date}`, to satisfy the modified query.*

Comment: You could also use Postgres 9.2 as it supports index only scans.  While its not an index organized table, I'd be hard pressed to pick MySQL over Postgres just for the fact that MySQL has clustered tables when Postgres's index only scans accomplish dang near the same thing and bring a wealth of other features.  Oracle and MS SQL are certainly options depending on your budget.

Comment: @rfusca I tend to agree on MySQL vs. PostgreSQL point, although there are more DBMSs to consider if you can live with just a covering index and not a full-blown clustering (DB2 comes to mind, probably Interbase/Firebird, some embedded databases...). I _think_ Sybase supports clustering, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use a database, but picking the right one for the problem would require a bit more information, especially about the format of the data. Here are my recommendations, with some details about when I'd choose one over the other:

**Relational:**

If all of your data fits the same schema (has all the same fields), then relational would make sense. From your question, you mentioned that you only need 2 indexes, `date` and `name`.

Assuming you have a lot of other data for each entry, an SQL database would make a lot of sense (using something like your query).

Benefits:

- You seem to already know how it works
- Very similar to the CSV style of doing things
- You can use SELECT/JOIN (if you need to later)

Downsides:

- Wasted space for unused fields
- Doesn't scale well (if you need more space)
- Might be overkill, because the problem isn't embarassingly relational

**NoSQL:**

If your data doesn't fit the same schema (a lot of different keys with only a couple shared keys), a document store would make more sense. Since your data is kind of relational, MongoDB would make a ton of sense.

I would use the following JSON guide for your database:

```
{
    "name": "MickyMouse",
    "date": ...,
    other fields...
}
```

I would set `name` and `date` to be indexes, just like in the SQL example. MongoDB is fast, and it doesn't take up space for extra keys.

Benefits of this approach:

- Scales really well (you can add nodes and shard)
- Really simple to work with

Downsides:

- Might not offer the features you need

**Conclusion:**

Both are good approaches, but it really depends on what exactly the data looks like. In general, databases are really good at querying, filesystems aren't, especially as the data gets big.

I would personally go the NoSQL route, but I would really need more information about the dataset and usage patterns. If the data needs to scale, then this is likely the best option.

I'm not really an expert, but I just don't like working with SQL that much. If the data is embarassingly relational, then SQL makes tons of sense, but it seems that everything you're doing would fit in one or two tables.

Comment: Given how mongodb stores things...I don't think eliminating the date would condense things much considering you're duplicating the 'name' over and over and over.

Comment: @rfusca - I think I misread the question. I made a ton of changes, so it's not really the same answer anymore.

Comment: You seem to be touting space as one of MongoDBs benefits and its generally really not....its one of most people's complaints.  Although there's no space used for unused fields - there's TONS of space used just to hold the names of the fields *for each row*, **because there is no schema***.  There may be may reasons to use MongoDB, but space isn't typically one of them.

Comment: *Wasted space for unused fields* Really?

Comment: @rfusca - This point only makes sense if there are a **lot** of differences between objects. For example, if the OP's csv had 100 columns, but each entry only defined a few (5 or so), then the resulting BSON could be significantly smaller than the SQL database that has to define each of those 100 fields for each record. But you're right, space isn't the primary reason to use Mongo, sharding and simplicity are, but for this problem it's possible that there are gains to be had. I removed the point in the bulleted list, but I still think it's a valid point in certain circumstances.

Comment: "nd it doesn't take up space for extra keys."—I don't know about other RDBMS's, but null values in Oracle don't take up space either.

Comment: @JackDouglas - I didn't know that. I assumed that SQL databases rely on consistent memory sizes to jump between rows in each table. Having empty fields would make that more complicated and slower. Then again, I'm not a database designer...

Comment: Many data types are not fixed length anyway—the constant is usually the block size, and typically a varying number of rows will fit in a block. Things get a little more complicated with blobs and other fields that are larger than the block size but that's basically how it works.